# Finding the mean of Python list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, mean

I am trying to find the mean of a Python list. When I print my list it is as follows:

```py
[array([0.33345667, 0.33523274, 0.33222637, 0.3341597 , 0.33329942,
       0.3330034 , 0.33197044, 0.33394078, 0.33458831, 0.33147091])]
```

That outcome is expected, there are no null values.

When I try `statistics.mean(accuracy_list)` (which is what I have done in the past to get the mean) I get this error

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this isn't a simple list: it's a list that contains a NumPy array with the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

`statistics.mean()` works on vanilla Python lists. It does *not* work on `numpy.ndarray`s. You should use [`numpy.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) instead.

Also, it looks like `accuracy_list` is a list containing a one-element `numpy` list. If that is the case, you can use list unpacking:

```py
import numpy as np
[accuracy_list] = [np.array([0.33345667, 0.33523274, 0.33222637, 0.3341597 , 0.33329942,
       0.3330034 , 0.33197044, 0.33394078, 0.33458831, 0.33147091])]

np.mean(accuracy_list)
```

Both of these output:

```py
0.333334874
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! Remember to accept the answer you find most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = [15, 18, 2, 36, 12, 78, 5, 6, 9]

import statistics
statistics.mean(l)
```

OR

On older versions of Python you can do:

```
sum(l) / len(l)
```

On Python 2, you need to convert `len` to a float to get float division:

```
sum(l) / float(len(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why there's a NumPy array in the list, so you could just extract it and compute the mean:

```
accuracy_list[0].mean()
```